# Sum of Subset for float values not working

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, numpy

I have written code for calculating subset sum which works like a charm for integer values but for float values it gives no result.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([15,1,4,6,3,10,4.2])
num = 8.2

def subsetsum(array,num):

    if num == 0 or num < 1:
        return None
    elif len(array) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if array[0] == num:
            return [array[0]]
        else:
            with_v = subsetsum(array[1:],(num - array[0])) 
            if with_v:
                return [array[0]] + with_v
            else:
                return subsetsum(array[1:],num)

print('\nList of Values : ',array)
print('\nSum Desired : ',num)
print('\nValues that add up to sum : ',subsetsum(array,num))
```

**Output for Integer Values**

```
List of Values :  [15  1  4  6  3 10  4]

Sum Desired :  8

Values that add up to sum :  [1, 4, 3]
```

**Output for Float Values**

```
List of Values :  [ 15.    1.    4.    6.    3.   10.    4.2]

Sum Desired :  8.2

Values that add up to sum :  None
```

How can i work with float values?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't, without additional work because decimal floating point literals do not represent floating point numbers exactly. You can try https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html  which also touches on some of the issues

Comment: Could you hint on what additional work I need to do to achieve my solution?

Comment: What's the expected o/p for the float case?

Comment: Expected output: [1, 4.2, 3]

Comment: Well, easiest is to use something like the decimal module. Another is to pick some acceptable precision (let's say, for sake of argument within 0.000001) - then instead of comparing for equality, you'd compare that the absolute value of the difference between the comparands is less than the selected precision

Comment: Does the order of elements in o/p matter? In fact, shouldn't it be `[1.0, 3.0, 4.2]`?

Comment: Yes..you are right. I just typed without keeping it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can simply use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to account for floating pt number comparisons. So, to solve your case, replace the equality comparison at : `array[0] == num` with : `np.isclose(array[0], num)`.

Similarly, you might want to make a similar edit at the start to fix : `num == 0`.

Comment: Its working but the output is [1.0, 3.0, 4.2000000000002]. I need [1.0, 3.0, 4.2]. How to achieve it?

Comment: @MukeshKumarMishra That `4.2000000000002` is  exactly the last element of your input. To see all 16 decimal places, set : `np.set_printoptions(precision=16)` and then print your input array. You would see that the last element is  `4.2000000000002` . Hope that makes sense. If you want to get an array as o/p, just do : `np.array(subsetsum(array,num))`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all numbers are greater than one, I think you can speed up the algorithm if you can eliminate any elements in the array greater than target.

I was able to get the code to work with some modifications to your algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
z=[]
def subsetsum(array,tgt):
    if len(array)==1 and array[0]==tgt:
        return tgt
    elif len(array)<=1:
        return z
    else:
        k,s=[],0
        for i in array:
            s+=i
            k.append(i)
            if s==tgt:
                z.append([k])
                k=[]
        return subsetsum(array[1:],tgt)

array = np.array([15,1,4,6,3,10,4.2])
num=8.2
array.sort() #speed up
array=array[array<=num] #speed up
print subsetsum(array,num)
```